# How to get description from tasklist or equiv

Tags: windows, taskmanager, tasklist, taskkill

I have a process (.exe) with a name that is too long.

It shows up in tasklist as HOTSPO~1.EXE, but I can see its fullname in Windows Task Manager, under "description".

How can I get that information?

I need it because I want to grep out the PID of this exact process and kill it.

> tasklist /v | egrep HOTSPO~1.EXE

This works - but I would prefer to specify the fullname to make sure I don't kill similar things by accident.

Comment: `taskkill /im FullImageFileName.exe` should do the job I reckon unless you will have more than one of these at a time.

Comment: @patthoyts No - that does not work I am afraid.